# getting a lot of empty white space underneath divs?

Tags: html, css

(Pretty new to this) I'm getting a lot of white space underneath my `.grid#` classes... I colored it with aquamarine to show the space that's being generated underneath the 2nd row of boxes.  If anyone knows how to fix this so the extra space is gone that'd be very helpful.

I think it may be the grid classes that are messing it up, but I'm not sure how to streamline this.

```css
div{
        background-color:aquamarine;

    }

    .grid1 {
        float: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:25vw;
        max-width: 25vh;
        height: 25vw;
        max-height: 25vh;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .grid2 {
        float: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:75vw;
        max-width: 75vh;
        height: 75vw;
        max-height: 75vh;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    .box {
        background: red;
        margin: 5px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .box:after {
        content: "";
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 100%;
    }

    .box > div {
        background-position: center;
        background-size:cover;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }
    .inner1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .inner2 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="grid1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner1">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: height:75vh;max-height:75vh;  are sizing grid2. did you write this CSS ? If not did you read it to understand what style goes for which ?

Comment: `center` is not a valid value for `float` fyi

Comment: no I didn't write it, it's part of a class exercise - the heights were it though thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best practices in template creation/integration is to use bootstrap.
Bootstrap is a growing standard for a valid reason..so that you don't have to write a code that is hard to maintain and that will at the end do the same exact thing that bootstrap is meant to do and does very well..besides you'll be finding help way faster because everyone will understand what you're intending to do and how to correct the code..
anyway:
you must remove "height" in order to flex to the wanted size..

```
.grid2 {
    float: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75vw;
    max-width: 75vh;
    /* height: 75vw; */
    max-height: 75vh;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
        background-color:aquamarine;

    }

    .grid1 {
        float: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:25vw;
        max-width: 25vh;
        height: 25vw;
        max-height: 25vh;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .grid2 {
        float: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:75vw;
        max-width: 75vh;
        
        max-height: 75vh;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    .box {
        background: red;
        margin: 5px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .box:after {
        content: "";
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 100%;
    }

    .box > div {
        background-position: center;
        background-size:cover;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }
    .inner1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .inner2 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="grid1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner1">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="inner2">4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove in .grid2  remove the height: 75vw;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your .grid2 class. You can either remove the Height property or set it to a appropriate value.

```
.grid2 {
        float: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:75vw;
        max-width: 75vh;
        max-height: 75vh;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
```